# WPF C# Dynamic event routing in programmatically created element

Tags: c#, wpf

I've provided, in a seperated class, some methods to create an element dynamically. Creating that element dynamically is not the problem but routing the event.

My thoughts where that the "path" (like namespace.class.method) is submitted via a parameter in the creating method.

But up to now, I was not able to attach such an event listener. I did many researches using Google and StackOverflow, but without any success.

I post the source code of the method below.
The code in the if-section for "EventHandler" is not empty was my last attempt. 
Is it possible that my thoughts will work or is it only possible to attach event handlers in the main class that is initializing the app.

```
static public WrapPanel comboBox(string Name, List<string> Items, bool MultiSelection = false, string EventHandler="",string Label="", int Width = 0)
    {

        WrapPanel lPanel = new WrapPanel();
        lPanel.Name = "stPanel_" + Name;

        if (Label != "")
        {
            Label lLabel = new Label();
            lLabel.Content = Label;
            lPanel.Children.Add(lLabel);
            if (Width != 0)
            {
                lPanel.Width = Width;
            }
        }

        dynamic lComboBox;

        if (MultiSelection)
        {
            lComboBox = new ComboBoxAdv();
            lComboBox.AllowMultiSelect = true;

        }
             else lComboBox = new ComboBox();

        lComboBox.Name = Name;
        foreach (string Item in Items) lComboBox.Items.Add(Item);

        lPanel.Children.Add(lComboBox);

        ComboBox dkaf = new ComboBox();


        if (EventHandler != "")
        {
           string lClass = "";
           string lMethod = EventHandler.Split('.').Last();
           for (int lCounter = 0; lCounter < EventHandler.Split('.').Length - 1; lCounter++)
                lClass += EventHandler.Split('.')[lCounter] + ".";
            lClass = lClass.Substring(0, lClass.Length - 1);


            object dynamicObject;
            Type objectType = Type.GetType(lClass);
            dynamicObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = objectType.GetMethod(lMethod);
            //method.Invoke(dynamicObject, new object[] { });

            lComboBox.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(method);

        }

        return lPanel;
    }
```

Best regards
Chris

Comment: What happened to `DataTemplates` and `Binding`? All of this would be gone if you would use xaml instead.

Comment: It also looks to me like you should be using templating. In any case though why is this an event rather than just a method and why not define an interface which has a method/event so you can cast to that and call it rather than use reflection?

Comment: If this is "just" clicking then a button has click behaviour. You can template a button to look like whatever you like.  Hence the button that's shaped like a calendar here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29866.aspx even has parts which are disconnected.

Comment: this code is using wpf classes but it doesn't look like it at all! code behind instead of xaml, no binding, Hungarian notation instead of camelCase...